# How to use nodejs+socket.io on php-engine

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I don't understand how to use nodejs+socket.io for my php engine.

1. I have php-engine.
2. I have server with installed nodejs+socket.io
3. I'll don't know, how to send event (json - pref. etc.) from php-script's on socket.io the server, with privacy policy.

Or, how to use this ? if this is not php - so how i take userid/username/images?

All scripts what i see in the internet - without security and anyone can use not his username or userid (just change js), and nobody don't said, how to protect this.

Maybe u can help me and say how do this - with example code :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do at all. Is your server side code PHP or node.js?

Comment: What do you mean regarding Privacy policy? a security layer?

Comment: jli php-engine to website, nodejs+socket.io for real-time events,  BagosGiAr yeah, bad english, sry.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Security Layer, you should implement your own algorithm. I can't show you an example since it depends on your architecture.

IMHO, I suggest to Use [Stomp](http://stomp.github.com/implementations.html) over [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stomp.php) & [nodeJS](https://github.com/benjaminws/stomp-js). It is simple enough and can handle a great variety of messages (Most common is JSON-body-Messages).

To Scale this solution I would also suggest to Use [activeMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html). ActiveMQ is a Message broker and it can help you to implement your security layer since it provides a SSL support over STOMP and a [Username/password](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html) option.

This solution has been tested in real life to handle ~6k TPS.

Cheers!